How to apply all transforms in such way that the origin does not change?
I am trying to export my file to glTF format and so i need to apply all scale, location and rotation to all my objects. Is there a way to apply all of them to a scale of 1 at once or do I need to select each one of them and Press Ctrl+A and apply all transforms?
I don't know how to apply all at once, so I started to choose objects individually and pressing Ctrl+A and applying all transforms. But now some of my objects are having their origins changed to some other point which I don't want. I want their origin to be at a place I have put it. How can i do that?

You can select all objects and then press Ctrl+A to apply the transforms on all objects at once. But if you don't want the origins to change, you should not apply the Location.
To apply everything except for the location, press Ctrl+A and simply choose Rotation & Scale instead of All Transforms.

Applying a transform means, wherever the vertices of a mesh are, no matter how they got there, this is now the new original state. So this is where the mesh's vertices should be when no movement, no rotation, and no up-/downscaling i.e. a scale of 1 is given to them.
That's why applying transforms sets the rotations to 0° and the scale to 1 without changing the position of the vertices. However, applying the location means, no matter where the vertices are, this is their position if the object i.e. its origin is at the world center. Well, that's the simple explanation if all objects were on their own. With parenting it might be a bit more complicated, some child objects probably reset origins to their parent objects etc.
